# How to remove job in Quartz JDBC Store?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I wrote this method to remove a job from Quartz JDBC

```
public boolean removeJob(String jobName) {
    try {
        JobKey jobKey = JobKey.jobKey(jobName);  
        try {    
            Scheduler sched = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();  
            logger.info("RESULT: " + sched.deleteJob(jobKey)); 
        } catch (Exception e) {    
            throw new RuntimeException(e);    
        }    
        return true; 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

`deleteJob` is always returning `false`. So the job is not getting removed from the JDBC tables in mysql. What am I doing wrong. I only want to completely remove this job from the scheduler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you defined a job group during job creation? Then you may need to call `jobKey(jobName, group)`. You can also check if job exists with `scheduler.checkExists(jobKey)` method which will be good for debugging.

```
JobKey jobKey = jobKey(jobName, group);
if (scheduler.checkExists(jobKey)) {
    logger.info("job found with key: {}", jobKey); 
    scheduler.deleteJob(jobKey);
}
```