# How to unblock the jobs with triggerstate to ERROR in Quartz cluster in java

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

my context is followed:

My enviroment is composed from two machines with Spring boot and Quartz in cluster configured on both.
I have a Master job with *@DisallowConcurrentExecution* annotation, that turns every 30 seconds, takes the records, on DB, with id fixed and schedules the jobs slaves, always with *DisallowConcurrentExecution* annotation, that make a defined logic. In anomaly cases (example: sudden shutdown machine), seem that some the jobs dont't be able to terminate his flow, remaining in the ERROR state.

How can I resume or unblock those jobs are in trigger state to ERROR by quartz objects in java ?
Because, currently, those jobs id can't anymore to be schedule from quartz.

Application log says:

```
org.quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException: Unable to store Job : 'sre.153', because one already exists with this identification.
```

[image]

Comment: thanks also to the post at the followed link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53622605/how-to-remove-job-in-quartz-jdbc-store
I resolved my issue